# Best way to "fill in" an image in Python, using a reflection of the image itself?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

For an analysis, I'd like to take the a bunch of TIF images I have, and fill in the black background to create a perfect square.

[image: sea ice tif file]

I would like to keep the same general pattern of the image when I fill in the black spots, instead of just filling in the black with random bits of white and blue. My first thought for doing this is to impose some sort of symmetrical "reflection" of the image onto the black portions - the concept is detailed below.

[image: concept]

The thing is, I'm not sure how to go about this - my first thought was to convert the image to a NumPy array and copy the individual rows of pixels over for a pseudo-reflection, but that could take a lot of time since I would be accounting for the length of the black portion in each row, and it wouldn't even be the desired result. I was wondering if there was a package or method that did something like this already, perhaps in PIL.

Any ideas are appreciated, as I am not to familiar with image processing in Python (or in general) - thank you!

**EDIT**: Here is a [google drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BepHjgGTzA_uDCNIICHXYGNSF-vO33AV/view?usp=share_link) for the example image in question.

**EDIT 2**: Here is a [google drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/169azPhELlWwKFGi2Q6Rrj95-kOaBuwrf/view?usp=sharing) for another example, this time with two "overlapping" black background areas (in other words, the actual data has a corner)

Comment: please provide an example image (including "blank" space)

Comment: [mre] please. I need _source_ data, before you transform it into your first picture. -- in opencv, we call them "border modes", and you'd want the "reflect" border mode. I'm sure other capable libraries have similar notions. you _do_ need the picture content separately, and your first picture must result from a transformation, so the border mode can be applied, using data in the source frame.

Comment: **only** if you *don't* have that (because the following is enormous work and insane to do if you can avoid the problem in the first place), you first need a *mask*, separating black from content. then you need to find, for each black pixel, its distance to the edge of content, and the direction (vector). then you can do lookups.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I see what you mean, but those geoTIFF images in the google drive link are my first source of data. I get them from the NSIDC (https://nsidc.org/data/g02159/versions/1) and that is the format they are in. Does this mean I would need to go the second route?

Comment: what size of image do you have to deal with? is it always gonna be about a megapixel, or can it be much more? -- I think you'll have to... I see no way around knowing those edges, if you want this type of mirroring. if you don't know the transformation, you'll have to find the edges, with mask and distance transform as described. -- I'll play with this when I'm at home and don't forget.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz yes, this is going to be the upper limit of images I would be dealing with, 200 x 200 pixels

Comment: I just played with a distance transform. it's noisy near the edges... -- one would need to assume edges and locate them. -- hough lines transform would need some NMS... at least in OpenCV, because that just returns everything above a threshold instead of local maxima. -- I don't have anything "simple" to solve this. in any case, you'll need to get those lines. -- can I assume that those edges are always single lines, never a "corner" of the actual data within view?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thanks for spending time with this. I just looked through the data and unfortunately there are some cases where you can see an "corner" of the data (an example is added in the post). However, if the transformation is only possible when the edges are always single lines, I may be have to edit my analysis to fit this

Comment: this might be doable with findContours and some gentle approximation. then you'd have nice line segments to mirror along.